Running AC vent hose through water heater closet?
Is there a safety risk if I run an AC vent hose through the water heater closet? I don't mean venting the AC exhaust into the closet. The hose would run through there and then out one of two large vents to the outside.
Why would I do this? That's where I can vent a portable AC without having to cut through brick.
Is it safe?

What type of water heater i.e. electric resistance, gas, oil, heat-pump-electric? What else is in the closet? It might actually be beneficial to vent the hot exhaust into the closet (which has large vents to the outside, so it will leave eventually) to very slightly reduce your water heating costs, if there isn't anything in there that would be damaged by it.

@Ecnerwal I think most water heaters are designed in the name of efficiency to not do heat exchange with the surroundings.  Also if it's single-hose A/C and you pump the hot exhaust into a closet, it will just circulate back into the house.   I've seen it work the opposite way ... cool a small room into a much larger one, EG the cashier's booth in an underground parking lot.

Just trying to think of reasons it would not be safe: If the hose is made of combustible material you need to look at the heater's clearance requirements. It probably is combustible and It's unlikely that in a "closet" you will have the right clearance.  You could avoid this by running metal dryer duct through the closet and attaching your A/C hose to one end, with the other end going outside.

@jay613 the question states that the closet has large vents to the outside. So I don't see it circulating back into the house, where presumably the only connection is the exhaust hose. However, if the vents are because it's a fuel burning heater, that hose would be an issue due to potential CO going though it when it's off. If the large vents are not oversized, there's also a potential issue of reducing the requireed vent area by blocking part of a vent with a duct for the AC Vent.

Ah, I read that as vents that would be added just for the A/C.  But I think your understanding (they are already there) makes more sense, so your suggestion is excellent.  IDK if CO is a concern.   Maybe.  It's probably designed to burn inside air, producing safe amounts of CO, and the outside vents are a bonus.  If it has outside vents because it requires them, that would lead to CO concerns, but have you seen such a water heater @Ecnerwal?

Not so much the water heater (there might be a few of the high-efficiency ones that are sealed combustion, but then, the heater would have a vent outside, not the closet having a vent) as the LAHJ regulations on the space a fuel-burning heater occupies (which vary with LAHJ.) Some do have very specific outside vent requirements, some apparently don't care at all.

What is the purpose of the "two large vents?"  Is one of them for the (gas?) water heater itself?
